# Ambiguity between getters and properties in Kotlin, best practices?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am using Intellij's Java to Kotlin converter.

When converting a function like this (in this example it is an overriding function but this also applies to non-overriding):

```java
@Override
public boolean isX() {
    // code
}
```

it sometimes becomes

```
override val isX: Boolean
    get() {
    //code
    }
```

and other times it becomes

```
override fun isX(): Boolean {
   // code
}
```

Sometimes I get both at the same time and then the bytecode compiler complains I have two functions with the same JVM signature:
isX()Z

It seems as though both options compile to isX() with the Kotlin bytecode compiler and are accessible with function calls isX()

So, this leaves me wondering several things:

- Can we reference the property option with obj.isX() or obj.isX?  Are both equivalent?
- Which of these two declarations is better, the fun or the val property?  Which is recommended Kotlin style?  To me they appear equivalent, so it's not obvious which to choose.  The property uses "val" and not "var" so it's a read-only getter, the function is also a read-only getter.  As shown, they also both override functions or properties.  If they are equivalent, why are there two ways to do the same thing?  If not equivalent, what is the difference?
- Is this documented anywhere?  Haven't found any.
- Why does the Java to Kotlin converter seem to alternate between the two?  I cannot tell why it chooses one or the other.  Sometimes both are chosen.

Comment: I asked myself the same thing. [This post](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-should-i-define-function-or-property-6786951da909) argues that props are for state, and functions for behavior, and that kotlin makes it easier to stick to this separation than Java (e.g. you can have [custom property accessors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)). In your example, if `x` is state, I would call the val just `x`, not `isX` (entirely up for debate). As for the converter... it's not great, I ran into trouble as well.

Comment: OK, thanks very much for the links and the input.  The question of whether something is state is not necessarily definitive - a function like isX() that returns a boolean with no arguments would almost always be reflective of object state to generate the boolean.  And in fact you can extend this argument to most functions with no arguments, but not all I guess, it's possible that such a function would indeed change the object or do some other operation.  But with a name like isX() that would be very unlikely and misleading.  But the links supplied  here provide additional factors to consider.

Comment: Welcome. I agree that the distinction between state and behavior is not always entirely clear. As you mentioned, I use (extension) properties over functions in the large majority of cases, except if I have to accept arguments and/or want to trigger side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Property getter is called only by `obj.isX`, function is called only by `obj.isX()`

2, 3. From [official Kotlin coding conventions guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties):

> In some cases functions with no arguments might be interchangeable with read-only properties. Although the semantics are similar, there are some stylistic conventions on when to prefer one to another.
>
> Prefer a property over a function when the underlying algorithm:
>
> - does not throw
> - is cheap to calculate (or caсhed on the first run)
> - returns the same result over invocations if the object state hasn't changed

4. Converter isn't perfect, the code it generates is meant to be refactored afterwards by the programmer. Both function and property declarations are suitable for Java methods that return `boolean` and are named `is*` - the programmer should choose the declaration that suits his design better.

Comment: Thanks for the link, was not able to find that blurb about this topic myself.